# Script to transfer a folder through SSH property

Tags: linux, ssh, sh

I want to tranfer a folder through SSH from a client to server and from a server to a client as well. The name of the folder is always the same. Before the transfer I need to create the backup of the folder which I want overwrite.
So I've created two sripts, one for the download (servet to client) and one for the upload (client to server).

down_src.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

rm -rf ~/Projects/GeoPump/project_bk
mv ~/Projects/GeoPump/project ~/Projects/GeoPump/project_bk
rsync --delete -azvv --rsync-path="mkdir -p ~/Projects/GeoPump/ && rsync" -e ssh pi@25.30.116.202:~/Projects/GeoPump/project ~/Projects/GeoPump/
```

up_src.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh pi@25.30.116.202 'rm -rf ~/Projects/GeoPump/project_bk'
ssh pi@25.30.116.202 'mv ~/Projects/GeoPump/project ~/Projects/GeoPump/project_bk'
rsync --delete -azvv --rsync-path="mkdir -p ~/Progetti/GeoPump/ && rsync" -e ssh ~/Projects/GeoPump/project pi@25.30.116.202:~/Projects/GeoPump/
```

When I run up_src.sh, for example, I need to insert server password three times

```
andrea@andrea-GL552VW:~/Projects/GeoPump$ sudo ./up_src.sh 
pi@25.30.116.202's password: 
pi@25.30.116.202's password: 
opening connection using: ssh -l pi 25.30.116.202 "mkdir -p ~/Projects/GeoPump/ && rsync" --server -vvlogDtprze.iLsfx --delete . "~/Projects/GeoPump/"  (10 args)
pi@25.30.116.202's password: 
sending incremental file list
```

Now my questions are:

Is this the correct way to do this kind of tranfer?

Can anyone suggest me the proper way to create these scripts without insert password multiple times?

Comment: "The down_src.sh works well but the up_src.sh not." How does the second script fail? What does it do or not do? What error messages do you get?

Comment: @Kenster You are right. I edited the post.

Comment: You say none of the commands have any effect? Could you run `ssh -vvv pi@25.30.116.202 'rm -rf ~/Projects/GeoPump/project_bk'` interactively? Note the "-vvv" option to produce verbose output. If it works, try, the next command and the next until you figure out which command is hanging. If the command hangs, [edit] your question to include the verbose ssh output.

Comment: @Kenster like you can see above, the problem seems to derive from the authentication but I don't understand why (I'm newbie with the ssh key authentication)

Comment: The "authenticity" message is a normal thing to see if you've never used ssh to connect to the remote system before. You say the download script works fine, even though it uses ssh to connect to the remote system. Did you run your test as the same user who normally runs these scripts?

Comment: @Kenster Now the script works fine (it was my fault). But it requires three times server's password insertion. How I can avoid it? Sorry for the confusion and thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

For the up_src.sh script to work, you will have to ensure that the user on 25.30.116.202 has permissions without using `... && sudo rsync`